# How get Id value from inserted entity in ASP.NET Core Web API post method using AutoMapper

Tags: post, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core Web API has the following `Post` method to insert a new category entity in database:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] CategoryDTO categoryDto)
{
      if (categoryDto == null)
            return BadRequest("Invalid Data");

       await _categoryService.Add(categoryDto);

       return new CreatedAtRouteResult("GetCategory", new { id = categoryDto.Id }, categoryDto);
}
```

I'm using AutoMapper so I send the DTO from body request, and in `CategoryService` I get the entity using AutoMapper mappings and create it using my repository (using EF Core `SaveChanges`):

```
public async Task Add(CategoryDTO categoryDto)
{
     var categoryEntity = _mapper.Map<Category>(categoryDto);
     await _categoryRepository.Create(categoryEntity);
}
```

In this way the entity is created but in Post method the id value returned by `CreateAdRouteResult` is equals zero because it gets the id value from `CategoryDto`.

How can I get the id value of the entity inserted?

Is there any alternative to perform this operation with AutoMapper and get the id value of the created entity?

Comment: So you are trying to return last inserted `categoryId` right? If that is the case could you please share your `_categoryRepository` method body?

Comment: I'm not very clear about your question, the id can directly can in your categoryDto if your entity had the attribute of ID by **categoryDto.ID**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by assigning the entity Id (`categoryEntity`) to `categoryDto.Id` in my service:

```
public async Task Add(CategoryDTO categoryDto)
{
     var categoryEntity = _mapper.Map<Category>(categoryDto);
     await _categoryRepository.Create(categoryEntity);
     categoryDto.Id = categoryEntity.Id; 
}
```

Comment: nice, same as i guess :)